# 150 VDC power supply for motor

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, bridge-rectifier

I am looking to design a power supply but confused on specifics. I have a mechanical engineering background, but do not have much experience working with electronics. This is for a personal project I am working on. I bought a DC motor that runs off 150 VDC on two leads and 280 VDC on the other two leads. I am looking to build a 150V power supply for it. It needs to run somewhere around 600 - 1000 W (its a 1 kW but will not be at full load.) The input voltage is 120Vac.

I am currently looking at using a full bridge rectifier and then capacitance filtering. How do I choose capacitors and that would fit a rectifier to give me the desired output? I'm just confused on how to go about designing the filter board.

Also are there easier ways to go about this? I do not want to spend hundreds of dollars on a power supply, but I didn’t know if anyone had any ideas on a cheaper option other than just building it.

Comment: `I am currently looking at using a full bridge rectifier and then capacitance filtering.` What's the input voltage?

Comment: The input voltage is 120V ac

Comment: with an inductive motor as the load, you probably do not need the capacitive filtering. The rectifier bridge will likely be way cheaper than suitable capacitors anyway, so it's worth doing the experiment.

Comment: Neil- are you saying all I would need would be the rectifier? For this would I just need a rectifier with an output of 150V?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

120 V AC rectified will give you 168 V peak rectified with a large capacitor. This is more than 150 V. Your motor may or may not be happy about it long term.

Ignoring the capacitor all together will give you 118 V RMS on the DC side (input voltage minus two diode drops). There will be an audible 60 Hz humming but it will spin along.

2.6 mF gives 10 % voltage ripple and 160 V average voltage. The inrush current is substantial at 150 A without some kind of soft start and the PF very low when running.

[image]

Perhaps a thyristor + capacitor? That way you can get to 150 V DC and soft start the capacitor bank and motor. Personally, I would have looked for a 1 kW DC power supply with current limiting if it was for any fixed installation or some craptastic Chinese thyristor motor controller if it was a one-off hack.

Answer (score 0):

A direct rectifier to feed the motor from the grid will have a high start current, if you add a capacitor, that will be difficult to handle, a soft start is mandatory. I think it will cheaper to increase the voltage, with a transformer (isolated secondary) of about 30 V. Connecting secondary winding in series with primary, you can rise to 150 V - 2xDiode Vdrop, close to rated motor voltage. May be 24 V unit is cheaper if you can live with 144 V. You need a secondary > 7 A to support start current overload. The rated power of this transformer is VsecxIsec, so not a very huge unit.

First check if prim-sec are isolated, then connect one secondary wire to primary, apply power, and measure the total voltage at the output. Swap this secondary wire if the measurement is lower than the grid.

I suggest to use controlled bridge, you can find a not very expensive control board and you will be able to ajust speed ramp, for a soft start.
[image]